# Facebook - Comment as Page

Tags: chrome-for-android, facebook

When on my desktop browser, I am given the option when posting on somebody else's page to comment as myself or as one of the pages I have. But on my Galaxy S7, there seems to be no way to do this.  If I use the Facebook app, the option to "Comment as" is not even displayed. If I open up Facebook on my phone, on Chrome or on Microsoft Edge for Android, the option to "Comment as" does display. But as soon as you click your page, the checkmark automatically goes back to your personal profile. Even tried clicking on the "Desktop Site" option in Chrome, but this does nothing.

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: This sounds more like a question for Facebook support than an Android question. Since it's about how Facebook's website works (or doesn't!), it seems unlikely that this is something you can fix in Android.

Comment: @DanHulme - My question though is if I am loading the Desktop site, why would it be any different than on my desktop browser? Is this a User Agent String thing?

Answer (score 1):

Actually just tried installing Dolphin and the "Comment As" worked as expected. Must be some sort of glitch with Chrome and Edge for Android. I suppose it would be nice to know why these mobile browsers don't work though, or if there is a fix for them.